# Inception-v3 using RMSProp epsilon=1

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I just read the [Inception-v3 paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567), and its training code released by the authors. And I found that when do RMSProp
optimization, the authors used [epsilon=1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py#L81). However, to my knowledge, people usually used 1e-10 or some small values and Tensorflow set the default value to 1e-10.

So my question is how will the epsilon influence the optimization? Why we need a epsilon=1 here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Through this [github issue](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet/issues/149) I found a post explaining the value: https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/d/msg/discuss/1JDPbuHN39w/AVXdYeaDCAAJ

In this post one of the inception v3 authors explains that they needed such a high epsilon to train it with async SGD and that lower values might actually work (better) for sync SGD.